# ADODB Command failing Execute with parameterised SQL query

Tags: mysql, ado, jscript

I have the following JScript code:

```
var conn = new ActiveXObject ("ADODB.Connection");
conn.Open("Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=blah_blah_blah;User=foo;Password=bar;");
var cmd = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn;

var strSQL = "SELECT id FROM tbl_info WHERE title LIKE :search ORDER BY id";
var search = "test";

try{
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
    var param = cmd.CreateParameter(':search', 200, 1, 100, search);
    cmd.Parameters.Append(param);
    var rs = cmd.Execute();
    }
catch (ex) {
    Application.Alert("Error retrieving id information from database.");
}
```

I've verified (by printing them) that the Connection object is set to be the Command's ActiveConnection, the parameter object has the correct value and the Command object has the correct SQL query as its CommandText. I also inserted an alert statement after each line in the try block to see where the error was occuring - it's fine after cmd.Parameters.Append but the exception gets thrown upon running the Execute statement.

I've tried displaying the actual exception but it's just a generic 'Object error' message.

The query executes fine and returns the correct result set when I just execute the SQL query (without the parameter) straight through the Connection object, but seems to fail when I use a parameterised query with the Command object.

As far as I can see all settings and properties of the Command and Connection objects are correct but for whatever reason it's throwing an exception.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ODBC and ADO, generally speaking, a question mark `?` is used as the placeholder for parameters. Parameters are bound in the order they are appended to the `Parameters` collection to the placeholders in the command. In your example, replace `strSQL` with:

```
var strSQL = "SELECT id FROM tbl_info WHERE title LIKE ? ORDER BY id";
```

You can still name the parameter that you create, but the only purpose it would serve is to be able to reference it by name later (e.g., with `cmd.Parameters.Item(":search")`).

Comment: That works great, thanks.

However, now I have a problem in that I also have other queries which use multiple parameters, but they all use the _same_ parameter. So I have one parameter (called :search for example) which is referenced multiple times in the same query. Since, as you said, they're bound in the order they're appended to parameters the query fails since there aren't enough bound parameters. The query is dynamically generated so it's impossible to know exactly how many parameters there needs to be. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @AdamLazaruso, not that I know of. In a similar situation before, I created and appended the parameters as I built the query up.

Comment: That could be tricky for my code, but if there isn't any other way I'm sure I can make it work. Thanks!