# ASP javascript how to create an SQL SELECT statement using prepared statement

Tags: asp-classic

I am using ASP javascript to select from a MySQL database using a parameter passed by the user.
I would like to do this using a prepared statement. I have seen examples in VB script but can't figure it out in ASP JS.
I would normally do it in the following way:

```
var adoConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
adoConnection.Open("dsn=my-dsn;uid=userid;pwd=password;");


var getAdmin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '"+String(Request.QueryString("username"))+"'";
var rsAdmin = adoConnection.Execute(getAdmin);
```

I would like to change this to pass the user data in a safer way, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to parametrize correctly in ASP your Queries, you need to use "**ADODB.Command**" to execute your queries instead of using **ADODB.Connection** directly. **ADODB.Command** has method named "**.CreateParameter()**" that permits that you want.

Example code

```
'-------------------------------------------------------------------'
var oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
var sSQL = "SELECT username, action FROM userlog WHERE event_date < ? ;";
oCmd.CommandText = sSQL
oCmd.ActiveConnection= oConn
'-------------------------------------------------------------------'
var oPar = oCmd.CreateParameter("event_date",7,1,,dDate); 'Date
oCmd.Parameters.Append(oPar);
'-------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

.... do this until you have all the parameters appended and ....

```
var oRS = oCmd.Execute();
```

and you manipule the recordset as you wish

**Aditional resources**

[ADODB Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675790%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

ASP javascript is usually reffered to as JScript. If you search for '[jscript] [mysql]' on stackoverflow it will show you a question which will probably answer your question:

[ADODB Command failing Execute with parameterised SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064865/adodb-command-failing-execute-with-parameterised-sql-query)

You could also google 'msdn jscript ado' for additional samples.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was searching for ASP javacsript and returned little result then, the link posted was also very helpful. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although calling into a database directly from browser-side code isn't a preferred method of retrieving data into the page (most folks prefer AJAX/JSON requests these days...), you could definitely improve the security of your code by converting the SQL statement to a stored procedure call.

For details, see http://andrewu.co.uk/clj/stored_procedures_with_jscript/