# SQL query by date with reference in excel (cell)

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have Mysql query through VBA and having error when i used date from cell . I need to use cell value for looping purpose. I think its due to date format compatibility between excel and Mysql. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

```
For R = 6 to lastrow

SQLQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM Mfg.databasemodels_note where typeId = " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & R) & " AND date < " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & R) & " order by date asc limit 1;"
```

Comment: by the way, example of my cell value 10/26/2017  3:03:44 AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer** is that your sql string contains a date that's unrecognizable to MySQL. Put a breakpoint just after building the string, run the code, then look at the content of the string; how's MySQL supposed to make sense of it?

As per MySQL reference material (link below), here's your updated line of code:

```
SQLQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM Mfg.databasemodels_note where typeId = " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & R).Value & " AND date < " & Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & R).Value, "'YYYY-MM-DD Hh:NN:SS'") & " order by date asc limit 1;"
```

**Real answer** is that you never, ever want to build a SQL string containing user input, from scratch, because of [SQL injection risks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Read [How To Invoke a Parameterized ADO Query Using VBA/C++/Java](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/181734/how-to-invoke-a-parameterized-ado-query-using-vba-c-java) for a quick overview of what you should be doing (on top of running your own basic validation).

Reference material: [MySQL 5.7: The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) /  [Visual Basic for Applications: Format Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

Further reading: [VBA, ADO.Connection and query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters) / [ADODB Command failing Execute with parameterised SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064865/adodb-command-failing-execute-with-parameterised-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks @Excelosaurus.. Converting Date to string solve the problem. Thanks alot!!